# How to append .html extension to the url (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Nextjs 13.5.2 page directory.

I have a requirement which need to append ".html" to the url for the SEO purposes in Baidu.

For example:
[www.test.com/news/123](http://www.test.com/news/123) -> [www.test.com/news/123.html](http://www.test.com/news/123.html)

What I have tried:

- Rename the filename to [slug].html.tsx
- Using rewrites:

```
    async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/news/:slug',
        destination: '/news/:slug.html',
      },
    ]
  }
```

All these solutions are not working, is it possible to do this in Nextjs?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

1. Rename the filename to `[slug].html.tsx`
2. Add the code to next.config

   `pageExtensions: ['html.tsx', 'jsx', 'js', 'tsx', 'ts']`